# Express Validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express-validator for making a Nodejs MongoDB application. I've installed the latest version of express-validator and Node but coming across "TypeError: expressValidator is not a function" as an error.

```
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
        var namespace = param.split('.'),
        root = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

        while(namespace.length){
            formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
        } return {
            param: formParam,
            msg: msg,
            value: value
        };
    }
}));
```

Comment: Seems like it's an issue in the way "express-validator" is called. 
Try to look at its documentation to see how they intend it to be used.

Comment: it's working with version **@5.3.0** but not with the latest version **@6.8.1**.

Comment: How did you `require` `express-validator` package? And, what's `expressValidator`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should not require `express-validator` as `expressValidator`.
According to `express-validator` V 6.10.0 [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) you should do some thing like this

```
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

app.get('/signup',body('email').isEmail(), body('password').isLength({min: 5}), (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       // handle error
    }
    // save user in DB
});
```

we can also use custom validation for our fields checkout [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) for more information.